# (Por qué) Está bien dicho: "Voy a que me corten el pelo"

Tags: expresiones-fijas

Generalmente, cuando vamos a la peluquería, usamos esta expresión:

> Voy a que me corten el pelo.

Aunque sabemos perfectamente que va a ser una única persona la que haga esta labor. La pregunta es, ¿está bien dicho eso? ¿por qué?

Comment: I really like this question because it highlights when you would use "que" instead of "para" .. which might be a surprise to english speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usamos la tercera persona del plurar porque no queremos especificar quién. Mira la diferencia entre:

> Voy a que me corte el pelo

¿Quién te va a cortar el pelo? Alguien que yo conozco, o que los dos interlocutores conocen, Luis, María, mi tía...

> Voy a que me corten el pelo

No estamos determinando quién va a realizar la acción. De hecho, lo importante no es quién la realiza sino la acción en si: "cortarse el pelo"

Comment: Aunque la respuesta es correcta, siempre es útil añadir alguna referencia de autoridad. Según la NGLE, estas frases contienen un *verbo con sujeto tácito de interpretación inespecífica.* Pág. 3078: El término oración impersonal se ha aplicado también a las oraciones que poseen sujetos tácitos de interpretación inespecífica, como en *Dicen que las cosas mejorarán*. (...) Así pues, en este sentido particular de 'impersonalidad', la oración *Llaman a la puerta* es impersonal. No significa, sin embargo, 'Nadie llama a la puerta', sino (aproximadamente) 'Alguien no determinado llama a la puerta'.